# Reactive select input to update table

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to understand the reactive part in R shiny. In that process I am trying to update an output table based on the input change while selecting values from the age drop down. It seems to do it by the first value but when I change any value from the age drop down it won't update my table. The input I am using is `chooseage`. Below is the code which I am using.

```html
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyBS)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(disable = F, title = "PATH Study"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    menuItem(
      "Population Filter",
      uiOutput("choose_age")
    )
  )),
  dashboardBody(box(
    width = 12,
    tabBox(
      width = 12,
      id = "tabBox_next_previous",
      tabPanel("Initiation",
               fluidRow(
                 box(
                   width = 5,
                   solidHeader = TRUE,
                   status = "primary",
                   tableOutput("smoke"),
                   collapsible = F
                 )
               ))
      
    ),
    uiOutput("Next_Previous")
  ))
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Drop-down selection box for which Age bracket to be selected
  age_levels <- c("18 to 24 years old","25 to 34 years old","35 to 44 years old")
  
  output$choose_age <- renderUI({
    selectInput("selected_age", "Age", as.list(age_levels))
  })
  myData <- reactive({
    with_demo_vars %>%
      filter(age == input$choose_age) %>%
      pct_ever_user(type = "SM")
  })
  output$smoke <-
    renderTable({
      head(myData())
    })
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to ask us to sift through. You'll be more likely to get a  useful answer if you put in the time to make a [MCVE] of your app

Comment: Where is `with_demo_vars` defined? It seems very odd to have a `shinyServer()` inside a `server()` function.

Comment: I get an error, running the ui. `Error in menuItem("Product Category", selectInput("abc", h4("abc"), choices = list(a = 1,  : 
  argument is missing, with no default`. Do you need the shinyServer inside the server for some specific reason?

Comment: @divibisan I just removed the unwanted section.

Comment: You have an extra comma at `collapsible = F,` so the syntax is invalid. The variable `with_demo_vars` still isn't defined anywhere. Try running the code in a new/fresh R session to test.

Comment: @MrFlick I am actually getting it from a package which I am using and cant be added here. I am trying to understand if the worklfow for reactive way is correct.

Comment: So this is just hypothetical? There's not actually a problem that you're having? Are you just asking "am I doing this right?" Well, if it works, then you're doing it right. If it doesn't try to say more exactly about what are expect to happen and provide code that we can actually run and test with.

Comment: @MrFlick Well yes thats the code I am using but cant share the data hence the gap. What I am trying to do is if you see the drop down now, when I change a value in the drop down it should change the table being rendered.

Comment: Don't put your code in a "snippet block". Those are only for HTML+JS code, not R code. Also, your code **still** contains `with_demo_vars`  
 in your `myData` reactive object so we can't run/test it. And `pct_ever_user` is also not defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quick prototype for your task

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

# 1. Dataset
df_demo <- data.frame(
  age = c(16, 17, 18, 19, 20),
  name = c("Peter", "Mary", "Mike", "Nick", "Phillipe"))

# 2. Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # 1. UI element 'Age'
  output$ui_select_age <- renderUI({
    selectInput("si_age", "Age", df_demo$age)
  })

  # 2. Reactive data set
  df_data <- reactive({

    # 1. Read UI element
    age_selected <- input$si_age

    # 2. Filter data
    df <- df_demo %>%
      filter(age == age_selected)

    # 3. Return result
    df
  })

  # 3. Datatable
  output$dt_table <- renderDataTable({
      datatable(df_data())
  })

}

# 3. UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(uiOutput("ui_select_age")),
  fluidRow(dataTableOutput("dt_table"))
)


# 4. Run app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think youre shinyApp is over-reactive, as all functions in the server are executed straight away, without waiting for any selected input. So either it will break down or behave weird. So you have to delay the reactivity with `req()`, `validate() / need()` or with any `observeEvent` or `eventReactive()` function.

Maybe this snippet might help you, although there would be several ways to achieve the desired behaviour.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)

data(mtcars)
mtcars$age <- sample(x = c(10,20,30,40,50), size = nrow(mtcars), replace = T)
with_demo_vars <- mtcars

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(disable = F, title = "PATH Study"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    menuItem(text = "Population Filter",
             uiOutput("choose_age")
    )
  )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tableOutput("smoke")
  )  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$choose_age <- renderUI({
    selectInput("selected_age", "Age", with_demo_vars$age)
  })
  myData <- reactive({
    with_demo_vars %>%
      dplyr::filter(age == input$selected_age) 
  })
  output$smoke <- renderTable({
    req(input$selected_age)
    head(myData())
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```